# Users with 5k+ rep have "approve tag wiki edits" privilege but can't see list of suggested edits

Tags: bug, status-completed, suggested-edits, tag-wiki

The [approve-tag-wiki-edits](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits) page states that users need 5k reputation to approve tag wiki edits. However, there seems to be no way to see the list of suggested edits. The `/review/suggested-edits` page only shows a 404 *Not Found* error. Apparently, only users with 10k who have access to moderator tools can see the suggested edits.

I have experienced this on [tex.sx](http://tex.stackexchange.com) where I have over 5k reputation, but I assume it is so on all Stack Exchange sites and Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Seeing all pending edits is a 10k ability -- otherwise you should see `edit (0)` or `edit (1)` under a question in the normal course of browsing questions...

[image]
<sub>(source: [stackoverflow.com](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/wp-content/uploads/pending-edit-post-menu.png))</sub>

... and you can approve them then.

*Update (Jan 31, 2012):* 5k users *can* now view the suggested edits queue.

Comment: Thanks Jeff, I understand this now for questions and answers, but tag wikis do not have such an `edit` *link* like that but an bigger *Edit Tag Wiki* HTML *button* on the *info* page of the tag. Is the `(0)` or `(1)` then part of the `history` link? Like I said, I couldn't see anything there when another user told me about his suggested edit.

Comment: @martin only diamonds and 20k users can approve tag wiki edits, and all tag wiki edits must be by registered users (no anonymous tag wiki editing is allowed)

Comment: @Jeff: Sorry, but the [approve-tag-wiki-edits](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits) privileges page states clearly **"Reputation Required 5000"**. I think that is the case since the recent change of the tag wiki edit rules. So something is amiss here. Maybe its simply an error on the privileges page and the 5k should actually be 20k?

Comment: @martin it's voting versus instant approve. Regardless, you'd need 10k rep to see the list of pending edits which does include tags. I'll follow up with Sam to make sure pending edits show up on the tag page themselves.

Comment: I fixed it so it displays the links on the tag wiki page.

Comment: Would not be possible to let the 5K users see the pending edits for the tags where they are most active (e.g. for the tags where they had 100 votes)?

Comment: I still don't see anything on the tag I just edited that allows me to approve it... even though I have >5k rep.

Comment: @george I don't think you can approve your own edits.

Comment: @Jeff: Ah, yes. Someone just pointed that out to me. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

This is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign), and is the same for regular suggested edit approvals (2k to approve, 10k to view). You can approve the edits as you come across them, but they want you to have some time before they let you power through the list.

Comment: Thanks. Could you please tell me how I can "come across them"? Last time another user told me about his pending edit and I could see anything to approve on the info page of that tag.

Comment: Is this still the case or are they now available through the Review system (suggested edits)?

Comment: @MartinSchröder: Seems they are now included in the suggest edits review queue.