# Tag wiki edit permissions don't seem to be working for me?

Tags: support, suggested-edits, tag-wiki

I just tried to do my first tag wiki edit for [maven-wagon-plugin](/questions/tagged/maven-wagon-plugin). It said my addition was waiting to be peer reviewed. As my rep is reasonably high (>9k) I wondered how much more I need to edit them myself or approve edits. I was surprised to find on my privileges page it says "approve tage wiki edits 100%", and says the boundary is at 5000.

Is this a bug?

---

Update - I've searched a bit more on this and found [Users with 5k+ rep have "approve tag wiki edits" privilege but can't see list of suggested edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80709/)

However, looking around the site, it seems that the ability to approve, or vote on approval is fictional for users between 5k and 10k. It might exist in the code, but I can't find a page that actually allows me to do it - or have I just not looked hard enough?

Jeff said

> I'll follow up with Sam to make sure pending edits show up on the tag page themselves.

waffles then said

> I fixed it so it displays the links on
> the tag wiki page.

However this doesn't seem to be displaying.

Comment: FYI: Finding and voting to approve edits (of tag wikis, as well as questions and answers) is ***much*** easier when you reach 10k and can access the list of waiting suggestions from the [review](http://stackoverflow.com/review/) pages, until then you have to randomly stumble across something with a pending edit.

Answer (score 4):

Tag wikis have much higher requirements to edit than other posts, to edit tag wikis *without* going through the suggestion stage you need the [Trusted User](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/trusted-user) privilege (requiring 20000 rep).

Otherwise, all edits move to the suggestion queue, where a few users with the [Approve Tag Wiki Edits](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits) privilege can work together to edit a wiki.

Comment: If you can see the suggestion queue, can you tell me a tag-edit which is in the suggestion stage, with a pending edit? Then I can see if it is actually possible for me to vote

Comment: @Nick, unfortunately I only have ~750rep on SO. My ♦ on SU means I could point you to one there... but you don't have the rep to test there either. Looks like we need a SO 10ker I'm afraid... maybe hunt for one in chat?

Comment: Oh well thanks anyway. Probably quickest for me personally is just to get the extra 850 rep, but at the moment I doubt this functionality is ever used

Answer (score 3):

The 5000 reputation tag wiki approval privilege operates the same as the corresponding suggested edit approval permission on the 2000 reputation edit privilege. That is to say, **you have the permission but not the tools to just parse a list of them**.

When you hit 10000 reputation, you gain access to visibility into **the suggested edits queue**. This queue includes tag wiki edits. So once you get about 1k more reputation (given you say you're at around 9k), you'll be able to see the queue of suggested edits including tag wikis. Until then, you can only run into them if you find them on your normal browsing path. Now, tag wikis suggestions *are* somewhat harder to find compared to normal edit suggestions, but it's still viable. I've seen it happen on Game Development, if my memory hasn't completely failed me.

It takes **20000** reputation to actually edit all tag wikis *without* going through the suggested edits queue. It may seem awkward that you're able to approve the suggestions of other users but your own still need to go through the queue, but that's how the system works currently.