# Tag-wiki edit permissions

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki, tag-wiki-excerpt

Now that I've reached 5000 on SO, I've been doing some reviewing of suggested edits.

But when I edited a tag wiki excerpt, it told me that I didn't have edit permissions.

What??  I can approve TW edits, but I can't edit them myself?

---

[Apparently](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94447/tag-wiki-edit-permissions-dont-seem-to-be-working-for-me) this is status-by-design, just wanted to know what the rationale is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's called "Peer Review". That way at least one other person will look at it and accept it or will make sure that the edit burns in the eternal flames of the Failed-Edit-Hell.