# Don't display suggested edits tab to users between 5k and 10k

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, privileges, tabs

I read [Users with 5k+ rep have "approve tag wiki edits" privilege but can't see list of suggested edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/80709/162565) and [How to review edits?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1465/4012), and iiuc users between 5k and 10k reputation can approve suggested edits, but only if they "come across them" directly on the question page of the respective edit. However, they can see the suggested edits tab, which shows up as empty to them.

Couldn't the suggested edits tab be entirely hidden until you can actually properly use it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

All this isn't really true anymore. [You can access the suggested edits queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105755/roll-out-10k-tools-gradually-between-3k-and-10k-reputation-for-users-who-have-sh/105870#105870) starting at 5000 reputation.

The suggested edits tab appears empty to you because… it's actually empty. If you *were* unable to use it, you'd get the "this page requires more privileges" error.

Comment: D'oh! Beat me to it! Perhaps the post in question should be updated! *Going to do that now...*